# Install Bower components into two different directories?

Tags: javascript, components, sass, organization, bower

When using CSS and JS components, is it possible, or even, does it make sense to install them to different directories?

```
.
|-- app
    |-- scripts
        |-- components           # js components go here
            |-- backbone-amd
            |-- etc
    |-- styles
        |-- modules
        |-- partials
        |-- components           # sass components go here
            |-- normalize.scss
            |-- etc
```

What's the most efficient way to structure a project organized as such? Is there a good Grunt task to accomplish the goal of integrating bower installed sass components for a development environment?

Comment: By "js components", do you mean CSS files that are for specific javascript libraries?

Comment: No, I mean js libraries that are installed via [bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower).

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  If all of the Sass files are in one location and the generated CSS files are in another location, then it doesn't matter how you organize things.

Comment: @cimmanon - I'm not currently aware of any way to install components to two different directories via bower. I agree, it doesn't seem like a problem to have vendors localized to the directory of their function, but the .bowerrc file doesn't have any spec that I know of to define install paths for different file types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bower needs to keep track of every component you install. That would be very hard if they were split up in multiple locations. For Sass development, just put the components folder in the Sass search path.

---

There are [grunt tasks](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower) that can assist you in splitting it up if you insist on doing that:

*(though not recommended)*

- [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task)
- [grunt-bower-organiser](https://github.com/mavdi/grunt-bower-organiser)
- [grunt-bower](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower)

Comment: Thanks Sindre, I didn't think it was possible or really made sense. It just feels better in my head when files are organized as such. Appreciate all your hard work on Bower, Grunt, etc man! Thanks for pushing the web forward!

Answer (score 13):

There is a node package called [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) that provides a single command for managing alternate install paths.

run `npm install -g bower-installer`

Set up your bower.json

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "jquery-ui" : "latest"
  },
  "install" : {
    "path" : {
      "css": "src/css",
      "js": "src/js"
    },
    "sources" : {
      "jquery-ui" : [
        "components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js",
        "components/jquery-ui/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then run `bower-installer` command.

This will install `components/jquery-ui/themes/start/jquery-ui.css` to `./src/css`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can have `.bowerrc` files in different directories, where you can config `"directory"` key to point to bower components directory.

But you will need to `cd` to correct directory before `bower install whatever`:

```
app/
  scripts/
    .bowerrc
  styles/
    .bowerrc
tests/
  .bowerrc
```

Comment: This won't work as Bower will look for `bower.json` in your present working directory.